# Griddle, pass 2 variables to custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, griddle

How do I pass 2 or more variables to the custom component?
I have a Griddle grid in the return function:

```
<Griddle
  data={myList}
  useGriddleStyles={false}
  enableSettings={false}
  sortProperties={sortProperties}
  plugins={[plugins.LocalPlugin]}
>
  <RowDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition id="id" title="Id" customComponent={CustomLocation} />
    <ColumnDefinition id="name" title="Name" />
  </RowDefinition>
</Griddle>
```

and the custom component:

```
const CustomLocation = ({ value }) => (
  <Link to={`/testpage/edit/${value}/`}>Edit</Link>
);
```

I need two variables in the link. The first variable should be the value of the id column and the second of the name column. Currently I can only pass the id.

Answer (score 0):

To pass row variables, the best way is using redux and create a new component.
Code and example of this behaviour is on the official griddle documentation site "Get data from Row into Cell"